# How to Refer to Current Element Being Changed?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an element that has an onchange="", and I want to find the ID of the .closest('tr')

Problem is, I can't figure out how to refer to the element I just changed without having to use a unique identifier (as there may be more than one of this element on the page.) I thought it was some kind of $(this) - but that didn't seem to work.

Here is my code:

JS:

```
function updateChannel(){
    var channeltoupdate = $(this).closest('tr').attr('id');
    console.log(channeltoupdate);
}
```

HTML:

```
<tr id="U4Rxv">
<td>
    <select name="resolution" onchange="updateChannel();">
        <option value="">Select a resolution:</option>
        <option value "1.3"="">1.3 Megapixel</option>
        <option value="2">2 Megapixel</option>
        <option value="3">3 Megapixel</option>
        <option value="5">5 Megapixel</option>
        <option value="VGA">VGA</option>
    </select>
</td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because you're not passing any arguments to the function so it doesn't know what `$(this)` is. Try:

```
<select name="resolution" onchange="updateChannel(this);">
```

and

```
function updateChannel(foo){
    var channeltoupdate = $(foo).closest('tr').attr('id');
    console.log(channeltoupdate);
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/S3Pgt/)**

Better still, get rid of the inline JavaScript and add a jQuery event handler (within a document.ready call or after the elements exist in the DOM) for the change:

```
$('select[name="resolution"]').change(function(){
   var channeltoupdate = $(this).closest('tr').attr('id');
   console.log(channeltoupdate);
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/3NevJ/)**

Comment: Thanks! This worked perfectly.

I like to have the inline function - and then move it into the main js once it's working properly. Will do.

Comment: Don't forget to mention *where* the event handler needs to be put (even if it's obvious to some of us), otherwise great answer :)

Answer (score 2):

remove the `onchange` event from the markup and add a css class name for our jQuery selector. I added a css class name called `lookable`

```
<select name="resolution" class="lookable">
    <option value "1.3"="">1.3 Megapixel</option>
    <option value="2">2 Megapixel</option>
</select>
```

and script is

```
$(function(){

  $("select.lookable").change(function(e){
     var _this=$(this);
     // _this is the current SELECT element. Use that now
     var updatedChannel=_this.closest('tr').attr('id');
     console.debug(updatedChannel);
  });

});
```

Adding the css class name and using it in the jQuery selector is not necessary. You can use the name attribute in the jQuery selector. But if you want to do the same behaviour for multiple ***SELECT*** elements, it is a good idea to group them using a CSS class, instead of the name. I prefer to keep unique name to elements as much as possible.

Answer (score 1):

rather than

```
<select name="resolution" onchange="updateChannel();">
```

You should attach the event to the element in the javascript itself. Then you can use the $(this) selector.

E.g.

```
$('select').change(function() {
    var channeltoupdate = $(this).closest('tr').attr('id');
    console.log(channeltoupdate);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use event binding. `this` in your markup must be referring to the window.

```
$(function(){

   $('[name="resolution"]').change(updateChannel)
}

function updateChannel()
{
    var channeltoupdate = $(this).closest('tr').attr('id'); // here now this will be the select element
    console.log(channeltoupdate);
}
```

Or try this way using **[call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call)**.

```
    <select name="resolution" onchange="updateChannel.call(this);">
```

Now inside your function `this` will be the select element.

or explicitly pass the argument

```
    <select name="resolution" onchange="updateChannel(this);">
```

and take it

```
function updateChannel(elem)
{
 // here now elem will be the select element
  ...
}
```